# Dividing two numbers in a list, then storing that number as the value in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to read in lines from a text file (I already have done this). The lines are in the same format:
"Name", "number", "number".
I read in the lines and put each line in a separate lists, to make a lists of lists. 
I need to divide the third number by the second number from each line, then store the resulting number as a value in a dictionary, with the "Name" as the key.

```
for line in f:   
    list_words = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]
```

That is what I have so far, assuming f is a textfile that is already read in. I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
list_words = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]
d = {lst[0]: float(lst[2])/float(lst[1]) for lst in list_words}
```

Note that the list comprehension that creates `list_words` eliminates the need for the enclosing `for` loop.

*Caveat*: A `ZeroDivisionError` will be raised if one of your divisors has value zero.

---

An alternative approach is to add new key-value pairs at each iteration of a `for` loop on `list_words`:

```
d = {}
for lst in list_words:
    try:
        d[lst[0]] = float(lst[2])/float(lst[1])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

Comment: Unpacking works here too, doesn't it?  `{a: float(c)/float(b) for a, b, c in list_words}`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh With the overhead of more text for explaining how that works :)

Comment: Could I use a try and except to handle the ZeroDivisionError? Such as:

Comment: try:
    d = {lst[0]: float(lst[2])/float(lst[1]) for lst in list_words}
except ZeroDivisionError:

Comment: @JesseCollier Can't read that code well in the comments, but I think you got the idea.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Okay thank you for helping me!!

Comment: @MosesKoledoye for lst in list_words:
            try:
                d = {lst[0]: float(lst[2])/float(lst[1])}
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                d = {lst[0]:0}
            return d

Comment: Hey, sorry for the formatting, I believe I got the zerodivisionerror down, but it only gives me the division on one of the name, and not all of them.

Comment: A dictionary is a mapping whose keys are unique items. So there's no chance for duplicate names.

Comment: Right, but what if I need all of the names that come from lst[0] mapped to the float division, but all in the dictionary d. So the dictionary would be all of the names mapped to the division?

Comment: I don't follow. The result should a mapping of unique names to float values. Your dictionary has just one key?

Comment: So there should be mapping of unique names to float values. When I try to return the dictionary, it only returns a dictionary with one name and a float number.

Comment: Yes they definitely are. I put the "for lst in list_words:" above the line where d = ... because when I put it in the same line, it said lst was not defined yet. Would that be messing it up somehow?

Comment: Yes. That is only going to create a dictionary with one key-value pair, the one from the last iteration. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
d = {l[0]:float(l[1])/float(l[2]) for l in list_words}
```

will create a dictionary keyed on the first (i.e. position 0) item.

Notes:

1. If you've just read the file in, Python will regard the two number as strings, hence the need to convert them to floats.
2. You really should also consider some sort of error checking - e.g. what if there aren't exactly three items on the line? What if the numbers can't be parsed (e.g. what would happen if something in the name field contained a comma?)